# Feature request: Add sound

Tags: feature-request

As some problems can be identified by sound, it might be nice to add a feature where audio clips can be added to questions (and answers).

When the technology is available, adding a smell might also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I believe for most sounds the poster can adequately describe the sound so that readers will understand what is being discussed.

For those sounds which may be indescribable, the poster can upload it to youtube and post a link to that video in the question.

Comment: True, but the user would have to also have a youtube account, right?  Also if youtube ever shut down, or the clip was deleted it would become a dead link.

Comment: I don't see YouTube going anywhere anytime soon.  It's just too important in the social marketing arena.  If you don't have a YouTube account, it's free to create one! :)

Comment: @Tester101 just fyi, I think there is a huge hurdle that must be jumped to get the SE team to do customizations on functionality within a particular SE site.  I think also once a video of the sound is uploaded some of the responders can do a better job of describing the sound for posterity purposes.

Comment: What about adding the ability to upload videos directly?  This feature could benefit a lot of the SE sites.

Comment: @Tester101 the one big problem with allowing uses to upload videos directly is size.  Even for the images that are uploaded to the site, they are actually uploaded to third party sites so that load is not carried by SE.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed that this would be helpful, but for now, upload it to http://soundcloud.com/ and provide a link.  Youtube is a video site, not a site for high-quality audio.

Comment: Is soundcloud the imgur of sounds?

Comment: @MarkJohnson: More like the Flickr of sounds.  :)  imgur's for dumping files and hosting them, Flickr's for photographers to publish stuff, with discussions, comments, tags, etc.